# Finding objects in Core Data by array attribute, performantly in >10k elements

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data, nsarray, unique-key

Short:
I need to **find core data objects by** a key, which holds a **unique immutable array** (fixed length, but chosen at runtime) of arbitrary objects (for which not only **element membership**, but also **element order** determines **uniqueness**). **NSManagedObject** however **forbids overriding** `[isEqual:]`. Now what?

---

Long:
I have an entity (see diagram image for entity "…Link") in my Core Data model for which I have to guarantee uniqueness based on an attribute key ("tuple"). So far so good.

The entity's **unique attribute** however has to be an **NSArray**.
And to make things a bit more difficult I **neither know the class type** of the **tuple's elements**.
Nor do I know the tuple's element count. Well, actually the count is the same for every tuple (per core data context at least), but not known before the app runs.

There must **only ever be one instance** of my link entity **with a given tuple**.
And for obvious reason only ever one tuple instance with a given array of arbitrary objects.
Whereas two tuples are to be considered equal if `[tuple_1 isEqual:tuple_n]` returns `YES`.  **NSManagedObject forbids the overriding** of `[isEqual:]` and `[hash]` though, otherwise things would be pretty much a piece of cake.

**"…Tuple" objects** are created together with their array of tokens (via a convenience method) and **are immutable** (and so is each "…Token" and its data attribute). (think of "…Tuple" as a "…Link"'s dictionary key.)

"…Tuple" implements `"- (NSArray *)tokens;"`, which **returnes a neatly ordered array of tokens**, based on the "order" keys of "…TokenOrder". (**Tuples** are expected to **contain at most 5 elements**.)

I however **expect to have tens of thousands** (potentially even more in some edge cases) of "…Link" objects, which I have to (frequently) **find based on their "tuple" attribute**.

Sadly I couldn't find any article (let alone solution) for such a scenario in any literature or the web.

Any ideas?

[image: core data model]

A possible solution I've come up with so far would be:

1. Narrow amount of elements to compare
   by tuple by adding another attribute
   to "…Tuple" called "`tupleHash`",
   which is pre-calculated on
   object creation via: **Snippet 1**
2. Query with NSPredicate for objects of matching tupleHash (narrowing down the list of candidates quite a bit).
3. Find "…Link" featuring given tuple in narrowed candidate list by: **Snippet 1**

**Snippet 1:**

```
NSUInteger tupleHash = [[self class] hash];
for (id token in self.tokens) {
    tupleHash ^= [token.data hash];
}
```

**Snippet 2:**

```
__block NSArray *tupleTokens = someTokens;
NSArray *filteredEntries = [narrowedCandidates filteredArrayUsingPredicate:
  [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock: ^(id evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings) {
    return [evaluatedObject.tuple.tokens isEqualToArray:tupleTokens];
}]];
```

*(Sorry, markdown appears to oppose mixing of lists with code snippets.)*

Good idea of or just insane?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I might actually do that. SQLite, that is. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As recommended in a comment by **Joe Blow** I'm just gonna go with SQLite. Core Data simply appears to be the wrong tool here.

Benefits:

- Fast thanks to SQL's column indexing
- No object allocation/initialization on SELECT, prior to returning the results. (which Core Data would require for attribute checks)
- Easily query link tuples using JOINs.
- Easy use of SQLite's JOIN, GROUP BY, ORDER BY, etc
- Little to no wrapper code thanks to [EGODatabase](https://github.com/enormego/egodatabase) ([FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb)-inspired SQLite Objective-C wrapper)

Answer (score 1):

I strongly suggest that you calculate a hash for your objects and **store it in your database**.
Your second snippet will seriously hurt performance, that's for sure.

Update:

You don't need to use the hash method of NSArray.
To calculate the hash, you can perform a SHA1 or MD5 on the array values, concatenated. There are many algorithms for hashing, these are just two.

You can create a category for NSArray, say `myHash` to make the code reusable.

Comment: A hash (calculated on initialization) stored in database is what my "solution" would be doing (see 1. & 2.). But a hash alone does not guarantee uniqueness in any way. Example: when calling -hash on an NSArray you get its element count (due to performance issues otherwise, I suppose). If my tuples' elements now happened to be uniformly sized arrays, I'd get 100% false positives when only using hashes. Thus my snippet 2 (see 3.) was meant to be then run on the arrays of tuples with matching (pre-calculated and stored) hashes to find the actual matches.

Comment: Regarding your update: That's what I was saying. If the elements in(!) my tuple happened to themselves(!) be arrays (and to make things worse: of uniform length), then I'd get the same hash for every tuple in my data set (despite varying content), when calling NSObject's hash method on my tuples' elements for hashing them. Also not sure how using sha1/md5 instead would play well with my requirement of conforming to "isEqual:". Further more concatenation would also require encoding the elements, right? Potentially expensive overhead depending on input, no?

Comment: Say you have an array like: "string", 11, array("other string"), 22. The concatenation, using HMAC (a good algorithm) would produce: 5string31112otherstring322. Then calculate the SHA1/MD5 of the intermediate result and you're set for a recursive, unique hash.